# How can I merge two CSV files from command line?

Tags: unix, csv, merge

I have two CSV files with the same headers, called a.csv and b.csv. How can I merge the two files into a third c.csv, such that c is composed of all the rows from a and b?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A basic merge would be

```
 cat a.csv <(tail +2 b.csv) > c.csv
```

This will put all of `b.csv`after `a.csv`.

**Edit**
I've added the `<(tail +2 b.csv)`. It will skip the header in the `b.csv` file.

**edit2**

```
$ cat a.csv
hdr
a
b
c
$ cat b.csv
hdr
e
f
g

$ cat a.csv <(tail +2 b.csv)
hdr
a
b
c
e
f
g
```

IHTH

Comment: It's working. But I can't understand Why +2? The header is one line, right?

Comment: @AravindhKuppusamy : If you want replies from people be sure to include their `@nameNoSpaces` tag ;-) . The `+2` means "start on the 2nd line", right? Good luck.

Comment: why do we need to tail b.csv?

Comment: @alanrzhang. That is one way to skip the header line that is in the b.csv. Otherwise the header line would appear at the top and then in "the middle" of the final output. Try it with the sample data yourself to understand (-;! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to join two CSV files, though the below one-liner didn't work
`cat file1.csv <(tail file2.csv) > file.csv`

I had to, strangely, tell the **tail** to skip **0 lines**
`cat file1.csv <(tail +0 file2.csv) > file.csv`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the answer a bit because it didn't work in bash :

```bash
cat csv_1.csv > result_12.csv && tail -n +2 csv_2.csv >> result_12.csv
```

1. csv_1.csv keeps the CSV first line  column header and dump in result.csv
2. Remove the first line column header from csv_2.csv and append to result.csv

Comment: Just noticed your answer. I'm guessing you are using `sh` and not really `bash` (or a very old version of `bash`). `<(...)` process substitution is one of several "advanced" features that are not in `sh` and other shells (although `ksh93` and others DO have that feature). But your solution is good for systems that don't have process substitution. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer (ignore first row & add nextline)

```sh
 cat sample1.csv <(echo) <(tail +2 sample2.csv) > sample3.csv
```

Comment: Yours answer is wrong, you still end up with a header line too many, and it adds nothing to the correct answer already provided 6 years earlier.